# SAS EG 7.1 Task template, error : Shortcut does not exist in this container

Tags: sas

In SAS EG v7.15, I am trying to use a task Template I named m_OS ( a simple select distinct on one variable from one table) :

```
Select distinct no_us from entrp where catg ne "OS"
```

When I ask the Query Builder to use this Template in case to select no_us in another table "The_users", where no_us are not in the result of the Template m_OS, SAS display an error :

```
Shortcut does not exist in this container
```

I don't understand why I have this error even there is no errors when running the Template.

Please, can any one help ? Is it a bug ?

Hope my question is clear!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to install EG 8.2? If you can, try running it there and see if it happens.

Comment: unfortunately i can't. It is in my computer at work.